# Как определить максимально похожее строки?

Tags: python

Имеется база данных продуктов, и имеется спарсенные продукты. Многие названия отличаются.

Как определить максимально похожее из спарсенных продуктов к продуктам в базе данных.

Может есть какая нибудь библиотека на Python?

Например:
Спарсенные названия:

```
GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
GeForce GTX 1060
GeForce GTX 1060 5GB
GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design
```

Похожие названия в базе данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите примеры. А так мне подобное понадобилось для сравнения названия игр в стиме и в базе. Для этого, при сравнении, приводил к одному виду -- приведение в один регистр и удаление регуляркой всех символов кроме букв, цифр и `_`. Могу в ответе привести пример

Comment: @gil9red как определяли похожесть? Приведите

Comment: не использовали библиотеки fuzzywuzzy?

Comment: Не, у меня была ситуация, в которой можно было обойтись простыми способами. Не знаю какая у вас ситуация, возможно вам проще было бы и через fuzzywuzzy (например, если присутствуют опечатки)

Comment: А похожие названия нужно искать по заданной строке? Например, по вашему примеру это было бы: `if "GeForce GTX" in product_name:`. Либо вместо `in` прикрутить шаблон регулярки или шаблон wild-card

Comment: Нужно определить максимально похожий или несколько максимально похожих, так как я добавляю в базу данных результаты различных бейнчмаркетов

Comment: Ну например проверяем мы GeForce GTX 1060, по вашему алгоритму он в первый показатель и засунет, а это ноутбук,  у него вообще должны результаты быть другие

Answer (score 3):

Испробовал различные варианты

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import difflib
text = "GeForce GTX 1060"

choices = ['NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 (Laptop)', 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3 GB', 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3 GB GP104',
           'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 5 GB', 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB', 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB 9Gbps',
           'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB GP104', 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB Rev. 2', 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Max-Q',
           'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Max-Q 3 GB', 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Max-Q 6 GB','NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile 6 GB']

print(process.extract(text, choices))
print(difflib.get_close_matches(text, choices))
```

Результат:
**fuzzywuzzy**

```
[('NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 (Laptop)', 90), ('NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3 GB', 90), ('NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3 GB GP104', 90), ('NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 5 GB', 90), ('NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB', 90)]
```

**difflib**

```
['NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB', 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 5 GB', 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3 GB']
```

Answer (score 2):

Подобное делал для поиска цен из стима на игры из моей базы.

Для этого написал функцию, которая сравнивает приводя к одной форме полученные строки:

- В нижний регистр
- Удаление постфикса (необходимость из-за стандарта названий игр в базе)
- Удаление символов кроме буквенных, цифр и `_`

Например, в функцию передаются строки `The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt` и `The Witcher® 3: Wild Hunt`. После обработки эти строку станут `thewitcher3wildhunt`.

Пример:

```
def smart_comparing_names(name_1, name_2):
    """
    Функция для сравнивания двух названий игр.
    Возвращает True, если совпадают, иначе -- False.
    """

    # Приведение строк к одному регистру
    name_1 = name_1.lower()
    name_2 = name_2.lower()

    def remove_postfix(text, postfix='(dlc)'):
        if text.endswith(postfix):
            text = text[:-len(postfix)]

        return text
    
    def clear_name(name):
        import re
        return re.sub(r'\W', '', name)

    name_1 = remove_postfix(name_1)
    name_2 = remove_postfix(name_2)

    return clear_name(name_1) == clear_name(name_2)


# Пример функции поиска цены для игры
def get_price(game):
    game_price = None

    # Пример спарсенного списка игр из стима по предварительному запросу
    steam_games = [
        ('The Witcher® 3: Wild Hunt', 1199),
        ('Call of Cthulhu®: Dark Corners of the Earth', 199),
        ('South Park™: The Stick of Truth™', 1499),
        ('Dishonored®: Death of the Outsider™', 859),
        ('Dishonored - The Knife of Dunwall', 199),
        ('Dishonored: The Brigmore Witches', 199),
    ]

    # Сначала пытаемся найти игру по полному совпадению
    for name, price in steam_games:
        if game == name:
            game_price = price
            break

    # Если по полному совпадению на нашли, пытаемся найти предварительно очищая названия игр
    # от лишних символов
    if game_price is None:
        for name, price in steam_games:
            # Если нашли игру, запоминаем цену и прерываем сравнение с другими найденными играми
            if smart_comparing_names(game, name):
                game_price = price
                break

    return game_price


my_games = [
    'The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt',
    'Call of Cthulhu: Dark Corners of the Earth',
    'South Park: The Stick of Truth',
    'Dishonored: Death of the Outsider',
    'Dishonored: The Knife of Dunwall (DLC)',
    'Dishonored: The Brigmore Witches (DLC)',
]

for game in my_games:
    print('{:44} -> {}'.format(game, get_price(game)))
```

Результат:

```
The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt                     -> 1199
Call of Cthulhu: Dark Corners of the Earth   -> 199
South Park: The Stick of Truth               -> 1499
Dishonored: Death of the Outsider            -> 859
Dishonored: The Knife of Dunwall (DLC)       -> 199
Dishonored: The Brigmore Witches (DLC)       -> 199
```

---

**PS.** конечно не всегда это работало, но в этом случае руками искалась цена для игры.

Comment: Добавил пример, думаю ваш вариант ко мне не подойдет)

Comment: у меня просто 10 парсеров ждут функции определения id продукта. На данный момент я всю строку разбиваю на символы, составляю множества символов по длине и делаю запрос на точное совпадение, если результат равен 1, то наш вариант. Если не нашли 1, то потом прохожусь по базе данных с помощью LIKE %processor_name%. Но процент добавления слишком маленький, не больше 50%

Answer (score 2):

В таких случаях используют движки для полнотекстового поиска. Например Elasticsearch или Solr. Индексируете строки с названиями продуктов (то что у вас сейчас храниться в базе данных) и ищете наиболее подходящие названия используя поисковый движок. Оба указанных продукта очень гибкие, имеют много всевозможных парсеров, умеют искать похожие строки и даже по синонимам, и т.д. Поиск по индексированным данным очень быстрый.

Answer (score 2):

Я тут как-то уже отвечал на подобный вопрос с использованием difflib, но я не уверен, что этот вариант удобен в данной конкретной задаче.

```
import difflib
search='GeForce GTX 1060 3G'

heap=['NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB',
'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB',
'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060',
'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 5GB',
'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design']

print(difflib.get_close_matches(search, heap, cutoff=.8)) #чем больше коэффициент cutoff,
                                                          #тем ближе сходство. 1 выдаст
                                                          #только полное совпадение.
```

на выходе:

```
['NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB']
```

Comment: @difflib, а как посмотреть коэффициенты&

Comment: @danilshik а они подбираются эмпирически, потому что их невозможно определить заранее для разных строк. в теории, можно делать выборку, меняя коэффициент от 1 и вниз, но разброс "соседей" может быть большой. В данном примере cutoff=0.8 даст одно совпадение, а cutoff=0.7 - уже 3.

Comment: я хотел просто, если коэффициенты одинаковые у самых топовых, то брать оба

Comment: убрал коэффициент, начало выдавать вроде самые топовые